# How to link current user to their author page through shortcodes

Tags: filters, shortcode, urls, author

I need a shortcode to link the current logged in user to their author page but I couldn't make the function workable. Found this code based on another similar question [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130390/get-current-users-post-url):

```
<?php
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo '<a href="' . home_url() . '/author/' . get_the_author_meta( 'user_login', wp_get_current_user()->ID ) . '"> My personal page</a>';
    } else {
        echo '<a href="' . wp_login_url() . '" title="Login">Login</a>';
    }
?>
```

But it gets "syntax error, unexpected 'href' (T_STRING), expecting ';'" What is the error here?

I also found this code which doesn't get an error:

```
<?php 
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
echo get_author_posts_url($current_user->ID); 
?>
```

But if I put this into a shortcode using add shortcode function, it doesn't display anything.

This has been asked many times here and I have tried those answers but none worked for me. I'm lost and I'm not an expert coder so any help will do.
Thank you!

EDIT including shortcode:

```
/**
*Shortcode for user's author link
*/

function my_users_shortcode( $atts, $content) {
return '<?php
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo '<a href="' . home_url() . '/author/ ' . get_the_author_meta( 'user_login', wp_get_current_user()->ID ) . '"> My personal page</a>';
    } else {
        echo '<a href="' . wp_login_url() . '" title="Login">Login</a>';
    }
?>'
;}

add_shortcode( 'my_shortcode', 'my_users_shortcode' );
```

Comment: for giggles, try adding a space after /author/  so you would have `'/author/ '`

Comment: I don't get how is that the fix. I did it but still gets syntax error. Any other methods?

Comment: For the code I'd vote for a combination of the two - the first's is_user_logged_in and wp_get_current_user()->ID is sensible, but I'd use get_author_posts_url to construct the URL not trying to assemble it yourself. You may also need to esc_url the get_author_posts_url as you echo it - get_the_author_posts_link() does.

Comment: However I've tried copy & pasting your first block of code into my site and it works fine: I can't reproduce the syntax error. Can you show us your complete shortcode handler please?

Comment: I wasn't sure it was the fix, but I'm not getting a syntax with what you posted so I was just guessing.  I second the request for full code.

Comment: Please check the edit above, I included the full code for it now. What could be the source of the syntax then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to return a `<?php` block as text, which you don't need to do, and is the wrong thing to do - it won't get executed, even if you do return it correctly. Your specific syntax error is this bit:

```php
function my_users_shortcode( $atts, $content) {
return '<?php
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo '<a href="' . home_url()
```

where you have the `'` from the echo inside a string that you're delimiting with `'`s too, and you can see from the syntax highlighting here that it thinks the string ends with `echo '` and that the `<a href` is now PHP code again. If you did want to do that, you'd need to escape the `'`s with backslashes to make them part of the string and not the ends of the string, i.e.

```php
return '<?php  echo \'a href="\' . home_url(); ?>';
```

But you don't have to do that: since we're currently running PHP code in the my_users_shortcode handler you can just echo the link from there, rather than trying to return a PHP snippet to try and execute later (which won't work), i.e.

```php
function my_users_shortcode( $atts, $content ) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo '<a href="' . home_url() . '/author/ ' .
             get_the_author_meta( 'user_login',  wp_get_current_user()->ID ) .
             '"> My personal page</a>';
    } else {
        echo '<a href="' . wp_login_url() . '" title="Login">Login</a>';
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'my_shortcode', 'my_users_shortcode' );
```

That said, as discussed in the comments I would use `get_author_posts_url` to generate the author page URL rather than trying to construct it yourself, and I think you ought to have some `esc_url`s too:

```php
function my_users_shortcode( $atts, $content ) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_author_posts_url( wp_get_current_user()->ID ) ) .
             '">My personal page</a>';
    } else {
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( wp_login_url() ) . '" title="Login">Login</a>';
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'my_shortcode', 'my_users_shortcode' );
```

(and if for the future you want the text to be translatable you need to wrap those parts in [`__('')`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/) too)

Comment: Oh, now I see. Thank you so much!! Learned a lot as well. You're awesome man. It works!!