# How to link current logged-in user to their author page via URL (Beginner)

Tags: menus, urls, archives, author, blog

I require a URL that links the current logged-in user to their author archive page. I came across some code from a similar question [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/373592/how-to-link-current-user-to-their-author-page-through-shortcodes) (see below). It works for me but unfortunately, it links to the author page by using a shortcode.

I don't know how to edit this to make it work with just a URL, instead of the shortcode. (I am a total beginner but I try!). My end goal is to create a menu item using this URL.

```
function my_users_shortcode( $atts, $content ) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_author_posts_url( wp_get_current_user()->ID ) ) .
             '">My personal page</a>';
    } else {
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( wp_login_url() ) . '" title="Login">Login</a>';
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'my_shortcode', 'my_users_shortcode' );
```

Any help with this would be really appreciated. If possible could any answer be provided in layman's terms that *even I* can understand!

Thank you

Edit:

I also found this code:

```
<?php 
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
echo get_author_posts_url($current_user->ID); 
?>
```

This could do the trick (?) but I'm not sure how to use this as <strike>an HTML link</strike> a URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### UPDATE

As per the comment, here is the updated solution.

> **Note:** Before copy pasting, don't forget to change **somePrefix** with ***any other prefix***  to avoid conflict with any other
> shortcodes.

**Step 1:** Make sure you have this filter in `functions.php` (If not, copy paste it there)

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'do_shortcode');
```

**Step 2:** Use this snippet to return Author URL. Paste this in `functions.php`

```
add_shortcode( 'somePrefix_author_url', function() { 
    
    $author_link = get_author_posts_url( get_current_user_id() ); // original link
    $without_protocol = trim( str_replace( array( 'http://', 'https://' ), '', $author_link ), '/' );
    return  $without_protocol; // returns author link without protocol
    
});
```

**Step 3:** Go to Navigation Menu and add Custom Menu Link and use `[somePrefix_author_url]` in the `URL` field and 'My personal page' or something in the Name field.

**Step 4:** Test the link from the front-end if it works.

**Reason for using link without protocol:**

By default `http/ without colon` is appended to the **shortcode** for some reason after [this](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/commit/b1975463dd995da19bb40d3fa0786498717e3c53) update. This could be a bug or maybe not as this behavior can be intentional. Anyways, the above code is safe to use as WP will automatically append the protocol to the custom link in this case.

---

Yes, this will do the trick. For HTML link, instead of just the function that outputs the URL only, use this from your snippet:

```
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url(get_author_posts_url( wp_get_current_user()->ID )) .'">
      My personal page
    </a>';
```

It should output 'My personal page' text hyperlinked to the current user's author page.

**Additional Tip:**
You can get the user object with this:

```
    $currentUser = wp_get_current_user();
    $currentUserID = $currentUser->ID;
    $userAuthorLink = get_author_posts_url($currentUserID);
    $userFirstName = $currentUser->first_name; 

// and so on
```

Later in your code instead of repeating the call for same object with `wp_get_current_user()` and `global $current_user get_currentuserinfo();`, you can call the user object for once and use its properties as shared in the tip.

See [WP_User Class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/) for available object properties (ID, first_name, ...) and methods (has_role() ..)

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for the reply! Apologies, I just noticed that I made an error in my question. I am trying to work out how to get a URL from the bottom code (not an HTML link), that I can use as a custom link in the menu. If possible, could you provide the exact code that I would have to input into functions.php? E.g. Do I need to insert anything before the 'global $current_user;'? Like 'function...'? Thanks, sorry if these seem like silly questions

Comment: @DanielMoore I have updated the answer. Please check and mark it answer once it works. :-)

Comment: Wheyyyyy it works!! You're a legend! Thanks very much :)

Comment: You are welcome :)